# Inconsistent at-parameter output in mtext during plotting

Tags: r, text, plot

I seem to have some problems figuring out how `at=...` in `mtext(...)` functions.

If I plot some scatter plots with added text

```
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(20),x2=rnorm(20),x3=rnorm(20),x4=rnorm(20),x5=rnorm(20),x6=rnorm(20),x7=rnorm(20),x8=rnorm(20),x9=rnorm(20),x10=rnorm(20),x11=rnorm(20),x12=rnorm(20),x13=c(2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1))
par(mfrow=c(1,4))
plot(x1~x4,data=df);mtext(c("Scatter plot 1","Test"), at=c(1,1), line=c(0,1))
plot(x2~x3,data=df);mtext(c("Scatter plot 2","Test"), at=c(1,1), line=c(0,1))
plot(x5~x6,data=df);mtext(c("Scatter plot 3","Test"), at=c(1,1), line=c(0,1))
plot(x7~x8,data=df);mtext(c("Scatter plot 4","Test"), at=c(1,1), line=c(0,1))
```

I get something like

[image]

Why are the added texts being printed in dissimilar locations in respect to their plots? What makes `at=c(1,1)` function differently with each plot? There seems to be no consistency in this pattern.

Comment: Look at the `x`-axes.

Comment: Well now it makes sense. Do you know any way to overlook that? Meaning, is there a way to make `at(...)` accept any other input that axis coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in `?mtext`:

> at: give location of each string in user coordinates. If the component of at corresponding to a particular text item is not a finite value (the default), the location will be determined by adj

So you can put `at=Inf` and adjust the place with `adj`, it will work as if your `x-axis` went from `0` to `1`.

For example, you can try:

```
plot(0:10, 0:10)
mtext(side=1, line=0, at=Inf, "text 1", adj=0.9)
mtext(side=1, line=0, at=Inf, "text 1", adj=0.3)
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems way more practical.

Comment: @OlliJ you're welcome, it can indeed be pretty handy when you don't know the extreme values, like inside a function for example